# How to convert between different classes in C++?

Tags: c++

I have a question related to conversion of different classes as the following code script shows:

```
template<typename E>
class Coordinate 
{
public:
    E x_;
    E y_;
    Coordinate(E x, E y):x_(x),y_(y) {};
    Coordinate():x_(0),y_(0) {};
    ~Coordinate() {};
};

typedef vector<Coordinate<float> > Cordfloat;
typedef vector<Coordinate<double> > Corddouble;




int main()
{
    Corddouble myarray;
    Coordinate<float> value(1.2,1.3);
    // myarray.push_back(value);  // failed!!!
    // Option 1
    Coordinate<double> temp;
    temp.x_ = static_cast<double>(value.x_);
    temp.y_ = static_cast<double>(value.y_);
    myarray.push_back(temp);
    // Option 2
    // myarray.push_back(static_cast<Coordinate<double> >(value)); // failed!!!
    // Option 3
    // myarray.push_back(dynamic_cast<Coordinate<double> >(value)); // failed!!!

    return 0;
}
```

In the above codes I try three means to do the job. Only the first method works. It seems I cannot use `static_cast` and `dynamic_cast` for conversion directly. I was wondering whether there are other means of performing the conversion task.

Comment: Perhaps an overloaded assignment operator and do it internally manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a converting constructor **or** a conversion operator (you probably only want one of the two):

```
template<typename E>
class Coordinate 
{
public:
    E x_;
    E y_;
    Coordinate(E x, E y):x_(x),y_(y) {};
    Coordinate():x_(0),y_(0) {};
    ~Coordinate() {};

    template<typename T>
    /*explicit*/ Coordinate(Coordinate<T> const& o)
       :x_(static_cast<E>(o.x_))
       ,y_(static_cast<E>(o.y_))
    {
    }


    template<typename T> /*explicit*/ operator Coordinate<T>() {
        return Coordinate<T>(static_cast<T>(x_), static_cast<T>(y_));
    }

};
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a constructor in Coordinate that is implicit from another Coordinate thus:

```
template< typename E > class Coordinate 
{
  public:
    template< typename F >
    Coordinate( Coordinate<F> const& coord ) 
        : x_(coord.x_), y_(coord.y_)
    {
    }

    // rest
}
```

Alternatively in your constructor

```
        : x_( static_cast<E>(coord.x_) ),
          y_( static_cast<E>(coord.y_) )
```

Answer (score 2):

A templated constructor and templated assignment would do that job neatly:

```
template<typename E>
class Coordinate 
{
public:
    E x_;
    E y_;
    //...

    template<typename T>
    Coordinate(Coordinate<T> const & c ) 
    : x_(static_cast<E>(c.x_)), 
      y_(static_cast<E>(c.y_)) 
    {
    }

    template<typename T>
    Coordinate<E> & operator=(Coordinate<T> const & c ) 
    {
       x_ = static_cast<E>(c.x_);
       y_ = static_cast<E>(c.y_);
       return *this;

    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only cast an object from one class/struct to another class/structure if one is a subclass of the other, or there is a conversion operator or converting constructor defined from one to the other. (I'm leaving aside built in types here, which have clearly defined conversions).

You can use static_cast to convert from a class to one of its base classes.
To convert from a base class to a derived class, you must use dynamic_cast (which checks that the base class is actually a derived class object before letting the cast go ahead).

Coordinate<float> is neither a subclass nor a superclass of Coordinate<double>.

So your only solution is to write a conversion operator or converting constructor from Coordinate<float> to Coordinate<double>.